# need a result of "ls -al /" on a ubuntu machine ( 10.4 desirably )

Tags: linux, file, permissions, ubuntu-10.04

I accidentally executed "chown www-data.www-data /*" it was not recursive so i guess my ass is saved. can someone give me a list of permissions in root folder printed via "ls -al /" so i'll change them back? thank you

Comment: You might get an answer faster on askubuntu or serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all `root.root` as you would expect it to be :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop (32-bit):

```
(buzzle:bmc) ~ $ ls -la /
total 112
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Dec 10 07:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Dec 10 07:58 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 26 09:18 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 10 07:58 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 24 13:28 cdrom/
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  3640 Dec 26 09:33 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 139 root root 12288 Dec 26 09:34 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 24 13:29 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Dec 10 07:58 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Nov  9 08:04 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-26-generic
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root 12288 Dec  8 09:04 lib/
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Oct 24 13:26 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 26 09:34 media/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov  9 08:14 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 10 08:00 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 186 root root     0 Dec 26 09:33 proc/
drwx------  10 root root  4096 Oct 28 07:56 root/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 10 08:01 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec  5  2009 selinux/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 16 05:32 srv/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root     0 Dec 26 09:33 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  14 root root 12288 Dec 27 09:36 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Aug 16 05:32 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Aug 16 05:48 var/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Dec 10 07:58 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Nov  9 08:04 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-generic
(buzzle:bmc) ~ $ uname -a
Linux buzzle 2.6.32-27-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 1 23:52:12 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I also have a 64-bit server (Ubuntu 10.04) available, if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo ls -al /
```

You must be  having a  sudoer permission.